# WordPress Plugin: How to get data in JSON and use in android?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I uploaded a plugin on a WordPress website. It is working fine and fetching data. I would like to use some part of that data in android as a web service. How can this happen? Is it even possible?

I downloaded plugin and search URL's from where plugin is getting data, but didn't find anything. I have downloaded the plugin, but am not understanding it.

Comment: A wp plugin that showing live match score can i get this data in json response in any sense?

Comment: Yes i want to get data in PHp array

Comment: I just asking can we get data in json encoded form from wordpress plugin?

Comment: If it is possible then how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way could be using this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/
It creates an api for external sources and can also export wordpress content into json.